# Problema simulating FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, functions, variable-definitions

I am writing a procedure that simulates the findRoot built-in function using the same code that appears at chapter 6 of  $\textit{Programming in mathematica}$ by Paul Wellin. The code is the following.

```
findRoot[expr_, {var_, init_}, \[Epsilon]_] :=
 Module[{xi = init, fun = Function[fvar, expr]},
  While[Abs[fun[xi]] > \[Epsilon],
   xi = N[xi - fun[xi]/fun'[xi]]];
  {var -> xi}]
```

In the text, the code is tested with success, but when I test it it doesn't works. For example,

```
In[5]:= findRoot[x^2 - 2, {x, 2.0}, 0.0001]

Out[5]= {x -> 2.}
```

I tried to change the variable fvar by var, and the program works, but this is a reuse of names that makes mathematica color the variable var in red.

```
findRoot[expr_ == val_, {var_, init_}, \[Epsilon]_] :=
 Module[{xi = init, fun = Function[var, expr - val]},
  While[Abs[fun[xi]] > \[Epsilon],
   xi = N[xi - fun[xi]/fun'[xi]]];
  {var -> xi}]
```

I need some suggestion to clear this issue.

Comment: Ignore the red coloring of `var`. It is a warning not an error message.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon That is one possibility, but not yet is clear to me why the code works for the author of the text.

Comment: I suspect that it is a typo that was not caught in the proofing.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks.